# Is the [stackexchange] tag really needed?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

I was recently trying to find a [hang](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hang) (or similar) tag, and came across the [stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag - on non-meta Android SE.

There is currently no tag info.

The tag has:

- One question which is completely unrelated with the tag
- Four questions about the SE Android App (which would mostly be better asked on Meta with the tag [android-app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app).

While "Using a particular app on your Android device" is listed as being on topic, question about the Android app are best asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Since questions about the Android app and the SE network aren't a good fit here, how about removing the tag?

Comment: Why aren't questions about the SE Android app a good fit here?

Comment: @DanHulme Because the "About" section of the app says to ask questions about the app on Meta SE with the tag [tag:android-app].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and it should be burninated.

- Questions about the Stack Exchange Android app should go on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) with the [android-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) tag.
- Questions about the main site should come *here*, to Meta Android